# How to derive "da hast'n Hut auf"?

Tags: etymology

I have a curiosity for hats as symbols of status, for e.g. you can put a graduation hat  on an undefined lump  to make it look like a graduate student and less like a potato. Hence I wondered repeatedly which hat it is that is refered to by the phrase "Da haste aber'n Hut auf".

> Da der Hut auch Zeichen der Männlichkeit war, kann die Redensart "den Hut aufhaben" auch analog zu "die Hosen anhaben" gedacht werden.

(https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=hut&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&sp0=rart_ou&sp1=rart_varianten_ou)

Several sources indicate that the phrase is fairly new (o.c.). I need to be clear that this is **not the question**, although, the definitions don't exactly match my understanding of the phrase, e.g.:

- “die Verantwortung tragen; […] die Macht haben; zu bestimmen haben” (redensarten-index.de),
- “verantwortlich sein”, (duden.de: “Hut”),
- “to be in command, to be in charge” (dict.cc).

This too does not matter. I note for completeness sake and to pre-vent any argument that to me it means *to be in a dilemma*, which might be implied by “Verantwortung”. I cannot deny that it may also mean “die Karten austeilen” (s.v. “zu bestimmen haben”, redensarten-index), but from my experience, I guess, it rather means the opposite: ***to have one's cards dealt***. In other matters I refered to *Kappe*, “Das geht auf meine Kappe”, and *Deckel*, “ein's auf den Deckel kriegen” (cf. *Bierdeckel*).

That said, I would like to know: **is *Zoff haben* phonologically compatible**, if assuming that *hu-* could be *huge* as in *Hubert*, give or take, thus *hut-auf* ~ *hu-zoff*?

There is no `phonology`, hence `etymology` is still the appropriate tag for diachronic phonology.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you mean by "phonologically compatible", also compatible with what. The phrase "hat Zoff" sounds the same as English "hats off"; is that something like what you're getting at?

Comment: I don't understand this question. It is pretty much gibberish to me. "Zoff haben" and "den Hut auf haben" do not appear to be related at all. I'm not an expert regarding phonology but I don't understand where you see "phonological compatibility" (whatever that is exactly) beyond both expressions being from the same language.

Comment: I think you got the main notion of "den Hut aufhaben" wrong anyways. While there is a notion of *authority*, the main notion is *responsibility*, which has absolutely nothing to do with "die Hosen anhaben". My main concern with this "question", however, is: I'm missing the question. For now, it looks to me like an invitation to a discussion, which is definitely not the right format here.

Comment: @RDBury, I can find multiple results in books by proper researchers who use it in a similar way

Comment: Wir sind gespannt. :)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a few preliminary words are in order:

First, we need to differentiate between "hats" (*Hüte*) and "headwear" (*Kopfbedeckungen*) in general. Headwear is just a sort of garment like any other and hats regulate the temperature of the respective part of the body - here the head.

Some *hats*, on the other hand, may have originated in and evolved from such headwear, but have a ceremonial or status meaning attached to them. Their original purpose may have been protection (from temperature or weapons, in case of a *helmet*), but now they signify their wearers status and/or abilities. Siegfried and his stealth cap<sup>1</sup>), a bishop with his mitre or a king with his crown, they all have in common that their status is defined by what they wear on their heads.

Also notice, headwear is special among other clothing. When *Geßler* wants to abase the Swiss in Schillers "Wilhelm Tell" he puts his *hat* on the pole and declares that it has to be greeted like himself. His *hat*, not any other piece of clothing! It is also common to identify the wearer of a crown by just mentioning it. "The crown has ruled that ..." is regularly said when in fact the *king* has said something. The object *crown* is so much identified with its wearer that they can be interchanged.

Another indication of the ceremonial importance of hats is: we take them off to show respect. Either literally, when we do so during greetings or in phrases like *hats off to* some accomplishment of someone.

Why this all is the case (my supposition is it is because of the hats vicinity to ones head), would be interesting, but hardly a topic here. Suffice it to say hats carry more importance than other pieces of clothing for various reasons and they define the status as well as represent their wearer.

This is where the phrase

> den Hut aufhaben

comes from. To have (and wear) this hat is not just wearing one additional piece of garment but means to have some power (the ability to decide) which is represented by it. There are some ceremonial acts a king can only perform with the crown in place on his head - different levels of power, maybe, but the same principle applies: he has to have "den Hut auf" (*wearing* - instead of just *having* his specific type of headwear) to do certain things.

---

<sup>1</sup>) The *Tarnkappe*, from Old High German "tarni", "secretly", is acquired from the dwarf *Alberich* by *Siegfried* in the "Nibelungenlied". Interestingly enough, the "Tarn*kappe*" becomes the "*cloak* of invisibility" in English. Changing the language also changes the type of clothing.

Comment: "*Suffice it to say hats carry more importance than other pieces of clothing*". Nonsense. It is so entirely irrelevant to the question, it simply does not matter if it is correct or not. This isn't debatable.

Comment: @vectory: It is actually the reason why the proverb is "den **Hut** aufhaben, not "die Socken anhaben" or something else. Anyway, I will find some (completely unrelated) Avestian, Akkadian or Proto-Sanskrit words containing one of the letters "H", "U" or "T" to throw into the discussion to make my answer more to your liking.

Comment: If by Akkadian you mean Hebrew and by Avestan you mean Eastern Orthodox ... still, it makes zilch sense. Hebrew *sof* is the only potential etymon of *Zoff* (says Pfeifer) but Kluge who worked on Rotwelsch does not have it at all. What he does have is much earlier *zoffmagd* under *Zobel².*